# How to find out where floating point exception occured?

Tags: c++

I am currently using a large computational package written in c++, which I have downloaded from github and compiled myself as I want to use it for some work I am doing.

The code works well for most purposes. Unfortunately, I have found that for certain inputs the code gives the error: Floating point exception (core dumped)

Now, I am a beginner at c++ and I have had no luck trying to browse through the many scripts that make up the code. My question is therefore: Is there a simple way to get a c++ code to output which line and which script the error occurred? Being used to Python, this is where I would always start, but unfortunately the compiled code does not return any more details about the error. Do I need to compile it in  a form of debugging mode to get it to do so?

Comment: My first step would be to load the core dump file into the debugger.

Comment: @melpomene That would be a distant plan B for me. If you can repro the crash reliably, much better to repro it in live debugging.

Comment: Note that "Floating point exception" is not an exception in the C++ sense, but the name of a signal (`SIGFPE`), usually triggered by integer division by 0.

Comment: Maybe also relevant: There is try / catch in c++ (try except in Python).

Comment: @nada nope, C++ exceptions are irrelevant here.

Comment: If you downloaded code from github, your best bet would be to submit the bugreport to the repo owner. I doubt as a beginner in C++ you would be able to troubleshoot yourself, even with (quite limited in given circumstances) help from SO crowd.

Comment: @SergeyA They're unlikely to pay attention to it unless you can provide sample input and/or a line number. Not sure that I would

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should build the program in debug mode and run it through a debugger. It'll "break" when the error happens and tell you exactly what line of code triggers it. Furthermore, you can examine the values of variables in that stack frame *and lower* to diagnose the cause of the problem.

In fact, while developing, you should be doing this anyway.

It is impossible to give *general* steps as to how to do this, but if you're using an IDE (Visual Studio, Xcode) this should automatically happen; if you're using GCC on the command line, research GDB; if you're using Clang on the command line, research LLDB.

Speaking generally, though, a Floating-Point Exception (not a C++ exception!) is usually, and perhaps confusingly, triggered by an integer division by zero. Though, there are other reasons it can occur. You'll know more once you're debugging.

Comment: Depending on which type of FPE this is, you may also want to check which FPEs are enabled in the floating point environment. It could be that the thing you see is the result of something bad that happened before but the corresponding FPE is masked. You may want to enable additional FPEs to catch the problem as early as possible.